# How to locate the minimum pressure with longitude and latitude

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The data is a 3D array with time, latitude and longitude in order. I tried with `np.where()` to give the index of all the minimum values but it didn't work.

```
print(np.where(n == msl.min))
```

It gives the results as `(array([], dtype=int64),)`, but I really need the exact longitude and latitude.

Comment: Minimum pressure? Where is pressure information?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `min()` attribute in order to get the minimum value:

```py
print(np.where(n == msl.min()))
```

The problem is that you're calling `msl.min` without  parentheses, which returns a function object. None of items in your array is equal to function, so `numpy.where` gives you an empty array.

Comment: Still the same output:(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the min/max from a column, you have a numpy function which is named : **np.min()** and **np.max**

You can make something like that :

```
max_value = np.max(array['column_name'])
min_value = np.min(array['column_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where(msl==np.min(msl))` will do the trick.

#### Demo

I simulated your pressure data through a 3D array populated with random integers from 0 to 9 (minimum and maximum simulated pressure, respectively):

```py
>>> msl = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(2, 3, 4))
array([[[3, 7, 7, 0],
        [1, 0, 9, 8],
        [9, 4, 9, 4]],

       [[4, 2, 9, 8],
        [2, 4, 2, 5],
        [5, 4, 0, 4]]])
```

The toy example shown above represents the values of a certain magnitude (i.e., pressure) at 2 different times, 3 different latitudes and 4 different longitudes.

The following code gives you **the indices of the times, latitudes and longitudes** for the minimum value of the pressure (i.e. the location of the 0's in `msl`):

```
>>> idx = np.where(msl==np.min(msl))
>>> idx
(array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([3, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
>>> msl[idx]
array([0, 0, 0])
```

Please note that you need to execute `np.random.seed(somevalue)` first in order to obtain the same results on different runs (to reproduce the displayed results you have to set `somevalue = 1000`).